# React redux componentDidMount only runs once

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-redux` and `react-router-dom` to get navigation and state sorted in my application, but I've run into a problem. I have the following routes setup.

```
<Provider store={this.store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} store={this.store}/>
            <Route path="/clients" component={Clients} store={this.store}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

Then I have a child component called `Profile` which tries to read the context store. It works fine, but only the first time. I've simplified this as much as possible.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};

}

componentDidMount() {

    console.log('Called once');
    this.store = this.context.store;
    this.unsubscribe = this.store.subscribe(() => {

        this.forceUpdate();
        const user = this.store.getState().profile.userDetails;
        this.setState({user});

    });
}


componentWillUnmount() {

    console.log('unsubscribe');
    this.unsubscribe();

}
```

This means that once I navigate away from the page and come back, there is no store to use, so it cannot render the component. Can anyone advise on what I am missing here?

Comment: Why pass the store via `context` at all if you're using `react-redux`? Just wrap your `Profile` component in `connect` and use the configuration methods `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to pass data from the store down into your component.

Comment: Passing the store individually is not the right approach. You can wrap the `<BrowserRouter>` in a `Provider` HOC from `react-redux` and pass the `store` context to it. The store becomes automatically available to the components below the hierarchy and you can consume it in any component you wish by calling the `connect` method. See the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidUpdate to solve this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.store = this.context.store;
    const user = this.store.getState().profile.userDetails;
    if (this.state.user.id !== user.id)
        this.setState({user});
}
```

Comment: Im using react-router and react-redux if that changes any of these methods

Comment: I get `Conflicting inherited declaration React.ComponentLifecycle.componentDidUpdate was found in namespace internal` but I think that's just my IDE spazzing out

Comment: Looks like it doesn't compiles properly. React router fires 'mount' when you open the page and 'update' when you use history, or open a route with the same component

Comment: You can try adding some debug in to `shouldComponentUpdate()` to see if the component is ever thinking about updating. I agree with @danny-delott. You should use the `connect` function to pass data down from the store.

Answer (score 1):

That's **really not** how you should be using redux. You should initialise the store at the starting point of your app and just connect profile.

```
class Profile extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
   }

   render() {
     return (<div>{this.props.userDetails}</div>);
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  userDetails: state.profiles[ownProps.userId].userDetails
};

export default connect(
   mapStateToProps
)(Profile);
```

You should also manage the passing of a profile id from the upper scope.

Comment: Yeah thats the one I was using until I ran into this problem, what is the ProfileSelectors that you have used above?

Comment: It just returns state.profile.userDetails, it would be something you implement. The point of redux is to isolate component and store logic. I edited to make it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: I don't fully understand this. State is just an empty object here? state.profiles will be undefined until I run a `store.getState()` and then a `this.setState()` ? Are the local state object and the global store the same thing?

Comment: When do I initialise the state?

Comment: When you initialise the store. You would also need to have a reducer for profile that updates the state for the profile. Connect is just a method that connects the dispatch and state to your store.

Comment: Does the store need to be initialised in every component or should I do this just in the root component?

Comment: The root. This is where you give it reducers as well.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can make use of `redux` store is by making use of `connect HOC` provided by `react-redux.` That way you don't have to subscribe to the store and pass store down to the Routes as props

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Profile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
       super(props, context);
       this.state = {};
    }   
    render() {
      return <div>{this.props.user}</div>
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state)  => {
  return {
    user: state.profile.userDetails
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
----------

<Provider store={this.store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} store={this.store}/>
            <Route path="/clients" component={Clients} store={this.store}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```